# Apache Solr Multisite Search - multisite taxonomy facets not displaying

Tags: php, drupal, search, solr

This regards http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multisitesearch I'm trying to enable Multisite Search Facets (based on Taxonomies) for a few sites - the 'normal' multisite facets such as 'filter by site', 'current search' etc appear fine but facets based on Taxonomies do not appear not matter what I do. The facets are enabled & the blocks added to regions, caches cleared etc.

Tested in Drupal Core 6.20 with the latest stable version of Apache Solr & Apache Solr Multisite Search

Has anyone else successfully enabled this functionality?

Any help greatly appreciated

*Single Site Search facets appear fine